# linked files in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm having a problem with the linked files in the page that is affected by the scope of the .htaccess file.

Here's the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^tp_update/id/([A-Z0-9]+)/([A-Z]+)/?$ update_taxpayer.php?tp_id=$1&tp_type=$2 [NC,L]
```

I didn't get any error, and I can access this page:

```
tp_update/id/1234/ITP
```

But the problem is that, all the files which are linked to update_taxpayer.php is also being affected.
When I view the page source and click the link css file. It says the file isn't found:

```
<link href="../../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

And I get this:

```
tp_update/css/style.css
```

Instead of the link which I declared above.

How do I get around with this?Is there a proper way of linking files when mod_rewrite is enabled.

Comment: use absolute links in your included content css\images etc rather than relative ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use absolute links as Dragon suggested, or you can use the `<base href="absolut_base_url">`

What this does is make all your relative calls start begin at the absolute_base_url. So (using your style example) if you just had `css/style.css` as the href, the browser will attempt to call 
`http://yoursite.com/absolute_base_url/css/style.css`
instead of
`http://yoursite.com/absolute_base_url/tp_update/css/style.css`